# UV Grid not showing up

Tags: modeling, uv

I am currently learning to texture a model and I encountered a problem after unwrapping: the UV grid (checkerboard pattern) is only showing up on certain parts of my model and not in the others.

[image: 1]

Do you know how to fix it, please?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn`t unwrapped whole mesh. go to edit mode select all faces and when unwrap.

Comment: I already did it and I did it again, but it's not working. Could it be the seams that aren't well done?

Comment: Please post your Blend file, you can upload it here - http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I managed to make your mesh textured. go to edit mode, face select mode, then select all faces (hotkey A) and unwrap, then in UV image editor click browse image and reselect your texture.

Comment: Nevermind, it worked, I don't know what I did wrong but it's working, thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you, I think that I didn't reload the picture correctly.